# AutoCAD VBAロード時の現象

Tags: vba, autocad

AutoCAD2012を使用しているのですが、下記の現象が起こります。

VBAをロードしAutoCADウィンドウを最小にする。
タスクバーから再びAutoCADウィンドウをクリックして開こうとしても、ワンクリック開く事ができない。
(VBAをロードしていない状態ではクリックして開く事が出来ました。)

なにか解決方法はありませんか?
OSはWindows7 64bitです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ロードしているVBAのコードを質問に追加してください。VBAをロードしていると問題が生じるのですから、問題の原因はVBAのコードの中にあるはずです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

システム変数taskbarの値を0にすると回避できましたので、こちらで回避されてはどうでしょうか。